# Parallelize download and decompression of gzip file with python

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, gzip, zlib

I'm downloading tens of thousands of ~20MB gzip files and reading the .csv content into a dataframe.  The functioning code I use to download each of them is as follows.

```
def download(url, chuk_size=125000):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    gz = io.BytesIO(b'')
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
        gz.write(chunk)
    gz.seek(0)
    df = pd.read_csv(gz, compression='gzip')
    return df
```

I have tried parallelizing downloading and decompression with `multiprocessing` and `zlib`

```
# global
d = zlib.decompressobj(16 + zlib.MAX_WBITS)


def decompress(q, chunk, gz):
    chunk = zlib.decompress(chunk, 15 + 32)
    gz.write(chunk)
    q.put(gz)


def download(url, chuk_size=125000):
    q = mp.Queue()
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    gz = io.BytesIO(b'')
    p = None
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
        if p:
            gz = q.get()
            p.join()
        p = mp.Process(target=decompress, args=(q, chunk, gz))
        p.start()
    p.join()
    gz = q.get()
    gz.seek(0)
    df = pd.read_csv(gz)
    return df
```

When it tries to decompress the second chunk it gives this error and hangs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\anaconda3\envs\evedaytrading\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\anaconda3\envs\evedaytrading\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\PycharmProjects\EVEDayTrading\get_orders.py", line 19, in decompress
    chunk = zlib.decompress(chunk)
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

When I press ^C:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_orders.py", line 82, in <module>
    df1 = download_url(os1)
  File "get_orders.py", line 35, in download_url
    gz = q.get()
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\anaconda3\envs\evedaytrading\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 97, in get
    res = self._recv_bytes()
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\anaconda3\envs\evedaytrading\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 216, in recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv_bytes(maxlength)
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\anaconda3\envs\evedaytrading\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 305, in _recv_bytes
    waitres = _winapi.WaitForMultipleObjects(
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Extra info in case it's useful: it wasn't me who compressed the files and I don't know how it was done except it's a `gzip` file

How do I get the code I wrote to function? Are there any other ways to parallelize download and decompression? I'm open to suggestions, maybe `asyncio` or `threading`.

Comment: requests already automatically decodes gzip encoded content, are you sure you're not trying to decode it a second time again?  and why do you iter in chunks just to read the entire content into memory anyway?

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: @wim Good point, but it depends on the headers it is sent with.

Comment: @wim I'm reading in chunks because that was faster for some reason, and in my case requests did not decode the gzip

Comment: @KlausD. added the full error traceback

Comment: You are trying to decompress a chunk, not a file. While that can still work on the first chunk, it will fail on the other since a chunk alone is not a valid gzip stream.

Comment: Starting a process for *each chunk* seems insane to me.  There is a huge overhead for a process, and you're spawning one for each 0.125 MB chunk.  For a 20 MB file that will be 160 chunks.  Do you have 160 CPUs??

Comment: @wim i was trying to wait for each process to end to spawn a new one. This is my first time trying to parallelize

Comment: That's not quite sane either, if you wait for each process to complete before starting a new one then you are not parallelizing at all and may as well be using 1 process.  And since you're *downloading* tens of thousands of 20 MB files, you're almost certainly going to be IO-bound and not CPU-bound in the first place (i.e. there will be no benefit from multiprocessing, a thread-pool will probably be a better choice).

Comment: @wim thanks for the tips. I'm not sure which approach to take and, as I said in the post, I'm open to suggestions. I will look into threading. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One thing I could do was to pass the stream object directly to gzip, it not only makes the code simpler, but it also speed things up by about 2s, or 25%. Here is the old function I was using:

```
In [2]: import requests
   ...: import io
   ...: import pandas as pd
   ...:
   ...: def download_old_method(url, chunk_size=125000):
   ...:     r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
   ...:     gz = io.BytesIO(b'')
   ...:     for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
   ...:         gz.write(chunk)
   ...:     gz.seek(0)
   ...:     df = pd.read_csv(gz, compression='gzip')
   ...:     return df
   ...:

In [3]: %timeit df = download_old_method(url)
8.44 s ± 2.21 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

And now the simpler and improved function:

```
In [4]: import gzip
   ...:
   ...:
   ...: def download_new_method(url):
   ...:     r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
   ...:     gz = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=r.raw)
   ...:     gz.seek(0)
   ...:     df = pd.read_csv(gz)
   ...:     return df
   ...:

In [5]: %timeit df = download_new_method(url)
6.11 s ± 200 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```